# How to update array object value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to update array object value but not working. I am trying to update item value from an array But not updating. How to resolve this issue.

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.arr = [
  {
    lable: 'test1',
    item: 'Row6',
  },
  {
    lable: 'test2',
    item: 'Row9',
  },
  {
    lable: 'test3',
    item: 'Row4',
  },
];
}

 updateVal() {
    this.arr = this.arr[0].item = 'Row9';
    console.log(this.arr);
 }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srsirm?file=src%2Fapp%2Farrcom%2Farrcom.component.ts

Comment: Read about how `this` works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: `this.arr[0].item = 'Row9';`

Comment: just `this.arr[0].item = 'Row9';` without `this.arr = this.arr[0].item = 'Row9';`  ?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**
This will probably work

```js
 updateVal() {
   this.arr[0].item = 'Row9';
   this.arr = [...this.arr]
 }
```

I think you're confusing two concepts here.

1. Yes, you're supposed to give Angular a new reference to the array/object to trigger the change detection (thus triggering a rerender)
2. **BUT**, you're not supposed to assign the attribute to some string value (in your case `'Row9'`.

If you're trying to change the value of exactly one element, you can change it inline with `this.arr[0].item = 'Row9'`. However, as you might observe, no new render will follow your action. The content of the object in the array will change. If you wan't to trigger a new render / the change detection, you need to create a new reference to the array, e.g., `this.arr = [...this.arr]` (basically moving all list elements into a new list).

Comment: this.arr = [...this.arr] //<---- is not required